# Angular - Select and ngOptions - Define key for value added to model

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel, ng-options

I have the following:

```
<select class="input-lg form-control" ng-model="selections[$index]" name="potsel" ng-options="selection.sel._id as selection.sel.name for selection in pot.selections" required ng-disabled="clicked">
```

I have 4 dropdowns being created, and this returns to me a $scope as follows (on submit):

```
$scope.selections = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"]
```

Ideally, I'd like it look like this:

```
$scope.selections = [{"dropdown1":"id1"},{"dropdown2":"id2"},{"dropdown3":"id3"},{"dropdown4":"id4"}]
```

Note that "dropdown#" can be retrieved in the html by using "pot._id".

Been a while looking at this, and I can't see anywhere in ngOptions to define this. Any help please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while you can do this directly in html, you can surely do this in js

```
      ng-change="selectionObj[$index] = {} ; selectionObj[$index][pot._id] = selections[$index]"
```

or you can create a function, which will do above
         ng-change=addObject($index, pot._id, selections[$index])

```
     $scope.addObject = function(index, key, value) {
         $scope.selectionObj[$index] = { key : value   };   
     }
```

**EDIT**

sorry, replace $index with index.

```
         var obj = {}; 
         obj[key] = value; 
         $scope.selectionObj[index] = obj;
         console.log(key, value);
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm seeing a constant error, $index is undefined, when I try this.

Comment: Ignore above comment, I replaced `$scope.selectionObj[$index]` with `$scope.selectionObj[index]`. Issue now is that the object is being added but it is using the word "key", instead of the value... e.g. `$scope.selectionObj = [{key:"id1"}]`.

Comment: Yeah it looks like it was a type issue in the function, your EDIT fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like this is actually not needed, as it is causing a number of issues down the line with the Schema (dynamic key, mongoose stuff), but your original answer fits the new bill, i'm using: `$scope.selectionObj[$index] = { "id1" : value1, "id2" : value2 }; `